# Call to a member function paymentMethods() on null

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am working on creating a subscription module in laravel and facing this issue "Call to a member function `paymentMethods()` on null".  Here is my code can anyone suggest to me why I am facing this issue.

```
Call to a member function payment methods() on null
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\plan;
use Stripe;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class PlanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $plans = Plan::all();
        return view('plans.index', compact('plans'));
    }

      
     
   
    public function show(plan $plan, Request $request)
    {   
        $paymentMethods = $request->user()->paymentMethods();

        $intent = $request->user()->createSetupIntent();

      
        return view('plans.show', compact('plan', 'intent'));
    }
}
```

Comment: where is that code?

Comment: @kevin that is the same person asking the same question :P

Comment: @Nemoko I know, I raised a flag and it automatically posted that message

Comment: Aplologies it got posted twice with no proper data. I have edited the question properly now

Comment: I am new to laravel and I am following this blog to learn more about Laravel Stripe Subscription using cashier . Landed up with this error while following  the steps.                                           
 https://blog.codehunger.in/laravel-stripe-subscription-using-cashier-in-laravel-7/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `$request->user()` configured?
Perhaps you meant `Auth::user()`

Try `Auth::user()->paymentMethods();` instead

Comment: Thanks I will try this solution